# Calling an Actor in a Spray route and waiting for the Actor's response

Tags: scala, akka, actor, spray

After have used Play! Framework for a while, I'm taking a first look to Spray. I started from a sample I found on GitHub, now I want to modify it but it's not easy for me to get how it works.

How can I wait for a message from an Actor in the code below?

```
package api

import akka.actor.ActorRef
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import spray.routing.Directives
import core.ClassifierActor

class ClassifierService(classifier: ActorRef)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends Directives with DefaultJsonFormats {

  import ClassifierActor._

  implicit val classifyMessageFormat = jsonFormat4(ClassifyMessage)

  val route =
    path("classify") {
      post {
        handleWith { 
          // The ClassifierActor gets a ClassifyMessage and 
          // sends a ClassifiedMessage back to the sender.
          // How can wait for the ClassifiedMessage here 
          // and send a HttpResponse back?
          cm: ClassifyMessage => classifier ! cm
          // ???
        }
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't write our routing code so I don't know the best way but broadly you never wait: instead you hand the request over to an actor or perhaps an actor wrapped in a future via a tell that is responsible for sending the reply once the processing is complete.

Comment: I'm new to Spray, so I cannot get any advantage from your reply. I'd rather need a snippet of code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spray is already based on akka.io

Thus, if you want just to complete your route with actor response, you could use ask pattern

```
import akka.pattern.ask  
import scala.concurrent.duration._
implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds) // needed for `?` below

 val route =
    path("classify") {
      post {
        onComplete(actorResponse(yourActor, yourMessage)) {
          complete(_)
        }
      }
    }

def actorResponse[T](actor: ActorRef, msg: ClassifyMessage): Future[T] = 
(actor ? msg).mapTo[T]
```

If you want to forward request to your actor model and complete route somewhere in actor system, you need to forward RequestContext to actors. Maybe, this [example](https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/spray-actor-per-request) could help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! You might add 'import scala.concurrent.Future' since also Java has a future. And 'import akka.actor.Actor' just because also it is needed.

Comment: One important note: the person is already using actors (see the "classifier: ActorRef" in the q). If one is simply looking for a way to multithread response logic, Future[HttpResponse] is the way to go, not actors. See https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/actors_vs_futures.html

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at my example project.  [This service](https://github.com/gangstead/spray-moviedb/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/example/routes/MoviesRoute.scala) uses Futures to complete routes.  Like Rup commented, it's bad practice to wait for a response.  Return a future immediately and let it complete when it gets a result.

In your example `classifier ! cm` is using the actor "tell" pattern.  It sends a message `cm` to the `classifier` actor and moves on.  If you want it to expect a response back in a future use the "ask" pattern: `classifier ? cm`.  In your `cm` actor's receive method you will return a future with `sender ! responseMsg` which will return in a future.